# How to use KOIN ViewModel in Java classes?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, koin

I am currently implementing a [Koin Annotations](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/annotations/) to my project and I would like to know how to declare the `KoinViewModel` and shared its data between java class fragments?

```
@KoinViewModel
class TestViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _testData : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData("init") }
    val testData: LiveData<String> = _testData

    fun updateTestData(s: String) {
        _testData.postValue(s)
    }
}
```

eg:

```
public class TestJavaFragment  extends Fragment {

    private final TestViewModel testViewModelLazy = KoinJavaComponent.get(TestViewModel.class);

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        testViewModelLazy.updateTestData("newValue");
    }
}
```

I know this is incorrect because I am not getting the updated value of `testData` to another fragment class.

eg:

```
public class TestJavaFragment2 extends Fragment {
    private final TestViewModel testViewModelLazy = KoinJavaComponent.get(TestViewModel.class);

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        testViewModelLazy.getTestData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> {
            // here I am getting the "init" again.
            Log.i("TestJavaFragment2", s);
        });
    }
}
```

dependency versions:

```
dependencies {
    api("io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.1")
    api("io.insert-koin:koin-annotations:1.2.1")
    ksp("io.insert-koin:koin-ksp-compiler:1.2.1")
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you!